# ¿Cómo procesar varias peticiones POST y actualizar documentos con Mongoose en Node.js?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

¡Hola Comunidad!

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en la cuál me encontré con el siguiente problema. Para no explicar el funcionamiento de toda la app ya que es complejo, detallo puntualmente lo que necesito hacer.

La aplicación está vinculada con una tienda online (Ecommerce), y cada vez que entra un nuevo pedido o bien, el pedido se modifica, mi app recibe un objeto que indica sobre dicho cambio a una determinada ruta. Cabe destacar que dicha tienda online pertenece a un servicio externo brindado por otra empresa (tiendanube.com) que tienen su propia API de acceso libre.

El objeto recibido es del siguiente tipo:

```
{
  'store_id':123,
  'event':'product/created',
  'id':1948209
}
```

Por lo tanto, a modo de ejemplo, cuando ingresa un nuevo pedido, el backend de la tienda online me envía un JSON a la ruta específica de mi API con el número de tienda online (store_id), el evento (event), y un id específico y único del pedido. Si se modifica un pedido, llegará un JSON igual pero con un evento distinto.

En mi API hecha con Node.Js y Express, cuando yo recibo en mi ruta específica dicho objeto, tengo que hacer los siguientes pasos de actualización:

-Peticionar al backend de la tienda online (tiendanube) para obtener los datos del nuevo pedido o el que se modificó.
-Revisar en la base de datos de mi aplicación si el pedido existe.
-En caso de que exista, modificarlo.
-En caso de que no exista, crearlo.

El código que realiza toda esta operación es el siguiente:

```
module.exports.handleWebhook = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.body);
        body = req.body;

        //Obtengo los datos del nuevo pedido o su actualizacion
        const { data } = await axios.get(`https://api.tiendanube.com/v1/${body.store_id}/orders/${body.id}`);

        //Chequeo antes si existe en nuestra base de datos.
        const orderData = await Order.findOne({ id: body.id });

        //Si existe, actualizo con los datos recibidos en la peticion.
        if (orderData) {
            console.log("The document exists on the database!: ", orderData._id);
            Order.findByIdAndUpdate(orderData._id, data, (err, docs) => {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                else console.log("Updated Order by " + body.event + " with id: " + docs.id);
            })
        }

        //Si no existe, la creo con los datos recibidos en la peticion..
        if (!orderData) {
            console.log("The document doesn't exists! Creating new one... ")
            await Order.create(data);
        }

        res.sendStatus(200);

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Dicho codigo es ejecutado cuando llega una petición a esta ruta:

```
router.post('/wh-order', handleWebhook);
```

Por las dudas también, el Schema de "Order" que se visualiza en el código es el siguiente:

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const orderSchema = new Schema({

    id: Number,
    store_id: Number,
    billing_name: String,
    shipping_cost_owner: Number,
    shipping_cost_customer: Number,
    subtotal: Number,
    discount: Number,
    total: Number,
    shipping_option: String,
    created_at: Date,
    next_action: String,
    products: Array,
    number: Number,
    owner_note: String,
    cancelled_at: Date,
    closed_at: Date,
    read_at: Date,
    status: String,
    payment_status: String,
    shipping_address: Array,
    shipping_status: String,
    shipped_at: Date,
    paid_at: Date,
    order_picked: Boolean,
    order_packed: Boolean,
    order_asigned_to: String,
    order_problem: String

});

//Crear modelo
const Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema, 'ordenes');

module.exports = Order;
```

He aquí mi problema. Cuando recibo una sola petición a esta ruta, todo funciona de maravilla. El problema es que, en muchos casos, hay pedidos que se modifican masivamente, y recibo varias peticiones casi simultaneamente.
Cuando esto sucede, los pedidos en mi base de datos se empiezan a duplicar. Pareciera que mongoose no los encuentra (cuando realmente están) y los crea nuevamente.
Entiendo que el problema podría estar en que, al crearse un thread por cada petición que entra, el valor que me devuelve la base de datos de mongoose se reemplaza continuamente, pero realmente no se como solucionarlo o si hay algo que estoy haciendo mal.

A modo de ejemplo extra, y siguiendo los console.log del código, les muestro lo que me aparece en consola.

Esto es lo que se muestra cuando se recibe una única petición:
[image: Console log con una peticion]

Ahora, cuando se reciben dos peticiones casi simultaneas, pasa esto:
[image: Console log con dos peticiones]

Desde ya, muchas gracias y espero haberme explicado bien.

Saludos, Nahuel